# Product of indexed parentheses

Tags: factorial, products

I am struggling to see whether is it possible to find a closed form expression for the following product

$$(1+K)(1+2K)(1+3K)...(1+(n-1)K)$$

where $K$ is a constant. I tried to come up with a factorial type of answer but I could not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your idea of "closed form" include the Gamma function?

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is
$$K^{n-1}\left(1+\frac1K\right)\left(2+\frac1K\right)\cdots
\left(n-1+\frac1K\right).$$
Using $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ gives
$$K^{n-1}\frac{\Gamma(n+1/K)}{\Gamma(1+1/K)}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. If K's are integer, is it possible to reduce this to just factorials?

Comment: @nOp If $K=1$ or $2$, yes. If $K\ge3$ I suspect not.

Answer (score 0):

Some numbers if you want to do some pattern searching ...

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Those coefficients are Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want but if the expression above was $f(n,K)$, the following is true.

$f(n,K)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}s(n,n-j)K^j$ where $s(n,k)$ are the Stirling numbers of first kind.